# Cant export csv format in PLSQL developer

Tags: oracle, export, export-to-csv, plsqldeveloper

I have been having a weird issue for months. I use PL/SQL Developer. I need to export data multiple times a day but it needs to be in csv format. Anytime I try to export in csv format to my teams sharedrive I get the error  I/O error 64. I know this is not an access issue with the sharedrive as I have full access. The issue only ever happens also when exporting in csv format. It does not happen when I export as an excel file. However, the files need to be in csv format.

Strangely again the error never occurs when I export to my local drive on my PC (my documents folder). This is the workaround I use at the moment and then copy these files over to the sharedrive and delete the files from my local drive. This is not ideal though as the files I export do contain sensitive information. I am wondering if it is an issue with the sharedrive. However I checked storage space and it has plenty remaining.

Any help would be appreciated! I have ran this issue around the house in my company and nobody can work out a solution.

[image: Here is how the error looks]

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you export the data? PL/SQL has at least a few different ways to export data. Which version are you using? (Also, I'm not sure why someone voted to close this question. To me, this question seems clearly about a "software tool primarily used by developers".)

Comment: No problem Jon. I use the export query results button and I pick CSV format. I then select the folder I want to share the results to and this is when I get this error. I am using version 12.0.7.1837